# Can not set value in drop down list dynamically using PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I need one help.i need to set drop down value which is fetching from DB using PHP.I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
  $getcustomerobj = $dbobj->getFeedbackData($db,$id);
  echo ($getcustomerobj->companypro);
?>

<select class="form-control" id="company_pro" name="company_pro" onChange="selectProductCompany(this.value)">
<option value="">Select Company/Product</option>
 <option value="1" <?php  if($getcustomerobj->companypro == 1 and $_REQUEST['companypro'] == 1){ print 'selected'; }?>>Select Company</option>
 <option value="0" <?php  if($getcustomerobj->companypro == 0 and $_REQUEST['companypro'] == 0){ print 'selected'; }?>>Select Product</option>
</select>
```

Here i can get the value of `$getcustomerobj->companypro` as 1 but still unable to set it inside the drop down list.Please help me.

Comment: I assume it's because your `$_REQUEST` is asking for `companypro` while the select's name is `company_pro`

Comment: $getcustomerobj->companypro == 1 and $_REQUEST['companypro'] == 1 both may not be 1 at a same time ,so you have to use OR conditions for both

Comment: are you getting value of this `$getcustomerobj->companypro` ?

Comment: I have given a solution that is working in my server. Just check that.

Comment: Where does `$_REQUEST["companypro"]` come from? If you are referring to the select field, that one is called `company_pro`. Also, why do you check for that? if the change of the select value implies a form submit, then you should simply save the new state before you get the data from the database. This way, `$getcustomerobj->companypro` would have the new value and you wouldn't require to check for the $_REQUEST data.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default value for `$_REQUEST['companypro']` at the top of your code:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['companypro']))
  $_REQUEST['companypro'] = 0;
```

In this case, you have already `$_REQUEST['companypro']` variable, because at the first load it is empty.

Comment: i added as per you but still same issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
<select class="form-control" id="company_pro" name="company_pro" onChange="selectProductCompany(this.value)" autocomplete="off">
<option value="">Select Company/Product</option>
 <option value="1" <?php  if($getcustomerobj->companypro == 1 and $_REQUEST['companypro'] == 1){ print 'selected="selected" '; }?>>Select Company</option>
 <option value="0" <?php  if($getcustomerobj->companypro == 0 and $_REQUEST['companypro'] == 0){ print 'selected="selected" '; }?>>Select Product</option>
</select>
```

If it doesnt work then add to the form element add autocomplete="off".

Comment: What is value of $_REQUEST['companypro'] you are getting?